# How to correct Matlab function for bouncing ball travel distance calculation

Tags: matlab, distance, collision

It is formula that I use to find distance traveled by bouncing ball:

 
[image]

where: 
**h(n)** - total distance traveled by bouncing ball
**H** - a ball drop height 
**n** - number of bounces
**e** - coefficient of restitution 

I created Matlab function to do that calculation:

```
function distance = totalDistance(H, n, e)
sum = 0;
bounceHeight = 0;
    for i = 1:n
        bounceHeight  = H*(e^(2*n));
        sum = sum + e^(2*n);
    end
distance = H+(2*H*sum);
end
```

This function takes initial drop height **H**, number of bounces **n**, coefficient of restitution **e** and returns me total distance traveled by bouncing ball. 
Then I call this function in command window to check:

```
totalDistance(2,2,2)
```

The function returns wrong result. It returns 130 instead of 82.

Why the program does not work properly?

Comment: Do not be confused by bounceHeight variable. It does not matter at the moment. I was planning to use it later.

Comment: Do not use `i` as a [variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab) and don't overwrite the build-in function `sum`. That's bad programming and prone for errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, everything @Adriaan said in the comment applies.

You have a couple issues in addition to that: 
1. The variable `bounceHeight` is unused. 
2. You need to add `e^(2*i)` instead of `e^(2*n)`.

What you are trying to do can also be accomplished in simpler (and more efficient code):

`h = H + 2*H*sum(e.^(2:2:2*n));`

what the `sum` in particular does is sum over all elements of an array created by the variable `e` which is raised to the power of a list, beginning at `2`, ending at `2n`, in increments of 2.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ah, I think the "coefficient of restitution" is actually also an overwritten build-in in this case. I expected it to be just the regular exponential function judging from the OP's formula